# Remove whitespace above div in react app

Tags: html, css, reactjs, header, whitespace

I have a problem where I have created a header component but there is still whitespace above the header on every page I pull the header component in

this is my entire header component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import './index.scss';

export default class Header extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <ul>
          <div className="links">
              <li><Link to="quizzes">Quizzes</Link></li>
            </div>
            <div className="links">
              <li><Link to="categories">Categories</Link></li>
            </div>
            <div className="links">
              <li><Link to="create">Create</Link></li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

and this is my entire css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #bec0c4;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
.container ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 90%;
}
```

I have seen many answers saying to set the margin to 0 but this is still giving me whitespace at the top. if i set margin-top to -20px, it removes it but i dont like this solution

Comment: Please add the html and styling for the header, and it's content.

Comment: @OriDrori sorry im confused, that is already there ?

Comment: My bad. Missed the name of the component. The styles don't have the name header :) And it's not what I've thought anyway.

Comment: Can you add the CSS for the `.links` class?

Comment: there is no css for the links. all the css is pasted above which is the css on the class "container"

Comment: try * { margin: 0 } in your root index css file. if you created your React app through create-react-app  package you can see that inside a public folder their is a index.html file and in root directory their is index.css file as well. Some browsers add default space to you webpages and you can undo the effect by adding the code above to your index css file. Hope this helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most browsers (eg. Chrome) come with a default set of rules (user agent stylesheet) and set rules like `margin` in `ul`'s, so you likely have a `margin-top` (`-webkit-margin-before: 1em;`) set to your `ul`.

Set `margin-top: 0` on the `ul` will remove the space:

```
ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: ah right so my body { margin: 0} was not overriding the rule for ul, interesting

Comment: Note, margin in inside containers are overlapping by default. If you have multiple sibling elements with margin, the spaces will overlap vertically.

Answer (score 2):

I've set the `margin` for `ul` to zero (and included padding to force a default reset). Let me know if this meets your requirements.

You may want to have a look at tools like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) for future use.

```css
body {background-color: red;}
body, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-color: #bec0c4;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 20px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <div class="links">
      <li>
        <a>Quizzes</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <li>
        <a>Categories</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
      <li>
        <a>Create</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I added a `margin: 0` to `.container ul` to and it doesn't leave any whitespace. It was leaving whitespace before over the Header component. Here's a picture of how it looks now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First check the page using inspect element (Ctrl+shift+I = for google chrome in windows).

Then check if `<ul>` is consuming the whitespace, then set `ul { margin:0; }` or for anyother element which is consuming the space. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

In my case, following code snippet worked (Mentioned this in `app_directory/src/index.css`)

```
* {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to get rid of this issue!

One as mentioned by most of the people do `'margin: 0;'` or `'margin-top: 0;'` to your ul tag or the child you have in your header.

or

Second as mentioned by Bahu, you can go to your index.css or App.css the parent components css files and do this.

```
* {
  margin: 0;   /* or   margin-top: 0; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply a `reset.css` on your code, ensure your page loads this `reset.css`. If you are loading it from the homepage for example -`index.js`-, and then you open your browser directly on, let's said about_us' page -`about_us.js`-, then if `about.us.js` fails to load the `reset.css` you will have a standard page with all the browser's default styles.

So, always ensure you are loading your `reset.css` on all your routes to avoid default browsers' page overflowing.